# Windows 11 error 0xc0000221

Tags: boot, memory, bios, motherboard, windows-11

so i just built my first pc, When using 2 ram sticks (gskill trident z5 6000mhz ddr5) on my mobo (Asrock b650 pro rs) i’m getting this windows error Oxc0000221 .. i took out one stick of ram , mobo suggested to use slot 2 and 4 , so i took out slot 4 and it worked and booted to windows fine. however when i put it back i get the error , does anyone know what’s wrong?

full error:

```
Recovery
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
The operating system couldn't be loaded because the kernel is missing or contains errors.
File: \windows\system32\ntoskrnI.exe
Error code: Oxc0000221
You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.
Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings
Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings
```

I didn’t enable xmp/expo , i didn’t update the bios

Comment: Does it matter which stick of RAM is inside the computer? As in, does Windows load fine with either stick and just not with both, or does it fail with a specific stick, even if it is by itself?

Comment: ^^ or does window fail if you only have either stick in slot 4 ... (would indicate a possible memory channel error) ... What BIOS version do you have ... 1.21 came with a note: `"improve memory compatibility"` and the notes for 1.28 suggest some changes with RAM training too (though, that seems linked with XML/EXPO enabled)... seems an upgrade to one of these may help

Comment: Sounds like you should RMA the memory at the very least, after you remove and reinstall, the processor making sure there are no bent pins.

Comment: Both rams work fine i use one stick on slot 2. But i’m double checking now doing memtest. my bios is at 1.03 .. if both rams finish without errors i’ll try to update my bios.. if that doesn’t work is the motherboard problem? thanks guys alot for the help